# Backup mailbox in Exchange 07

Tags: backup, exchange-2007, mailbox

I need to do some clean up in my Exchange 07, so I want to backup some mailboxs before deleting them.

I found this : http://www.jasonmohan.com/exchange/how-to-pst-a-exchange-2007-mailbox/
I read also something about 32 bits limitation that is require to perform this backup.

I'm wondering if something more simple had come up in the SP2.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Export-Mailbox` command is really simple, and great for this kind of one-mailbox-at-a-time backup method. We use it all the time before deleting accounts. It has a variety of commands, and even allows you to export-to-pst whole folders if you want to be granular. By default is just exports the entire mailbox to PST.

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity JoeCEO -PSTFolderPath E:\MBackups\JoeCEO.PST
```

Alternately, you can back these up to another mail-store completely. It doesn't get it out of Exchange, but it does sequester the data in a spot you have more control over.

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity JoeCEO -TargetMailbox BackupStore1 -TargetFolder JoeCEO
```

Unlike the PST method, this can be done directly on the Exchange server.

Comment: Can it work directly from the exchange server 64bits ? Or I really need to get this done on a 32bits ?

Comment: The PST method requires a 32 bit machine with Outlook installed. However, if you don't need PST, see the edit.

Comment: If I get this right, I have to create a Backup mailbox, where I can transfert every mails in it in a folder ? So I can for example log in this backup account, and access every backed up email in each created folder?

Comment: @Bastien974 That's about right. You'll have one (probably very large) mailbox with folders for each of the backed-up mailboxes in it.

Comment: Great that worked, I had to manually add myself with Full Permission on each mailbox. I'm Enterprise Admin, Exchange Organization Admin, I shouldn't need to, why ?